# How to view a file written from an error during a Github action?

Tags: github, github-actions

I'm trying to install a module using CPAN but get this error:

```
Run cpanm --force DB_File
  cpanm --force DB_File
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
  env:
    PERL5LIB: /home/runner/work/Bio-STR-exSTRa/Bio-STR-exSTRa/local/lib/perl5:/home/runner/work/_actions/shogo82148/actions-setup-perl/v1/scripts/lib
--> Working on DB_File
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/P/PM/PMQS/DB_File-1.858.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring DB_File-1.858 ... OK
! Installing DB_File failed. See /home/runner/.cpanm/work/1660633817.1777/build.log for details. Retry with --force to force install it.
Building and testing DB_File-1.858 ... FAIL
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

How can I download or view the file `/home/runner/.cpanm/work/1660633817.1777/build.log` so I can diagnose the problem?

Github action YML file can be seen at https://github.com/bahlolab/Bio-STR-exSTRa/blob/master/.github/workflows/ci.yml.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at GitHub artifacts:
https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/storing-workflow-data-as-artifacts#uploading-build-and-test-artifacts

You can use that method to expose files as a downloadable resources.